# empty get in expression bodied syntax?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to write this property:

```
string Error { get; }
```

in expression bodied syntax (`=>`),

for example:

```
 string Title
  { 
    get
      {
        return title;
      }
  }
```

becomes:

```
string Title => title;
```

Comment: Why would you need it? :) `get;` is shorter than `get => anything`.

Comment: Just to make sure the expression bodied syntax can entirely replace the old fashion syntax.. I ask for curiosity

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, because this:

```
string Error { get; }
```

... is an automatically-implemented property. The compiler is generating a field for you behind the scenes, but you can't refer to that field within the code. If you need to use the backing field, you need to declare it yourself:

```
private readonly string error;
string Error => error;
```

That's basically what the compiler is generating for you - so if you want that, just write it yourself. It's pretty rare that that's useful though, IMO.

If you already *have* that field, you could either just write the property as above, or you could convert the field *into* the property, so use the property where you were previously using the field.

(It's more feasible if you want a property which is read-only, but backed by a mutable field - at which point it can't be auto-implemented if you want a genuinely read-only property. It could be a publicly-readable and privately-writable automatically-implemented property though.)

Comment: His example implies that the `error` field does exist in fact.

Comment: @marsze: I'm not entirely sure about that implication, but I'll make the answer cover it.

Comment: @marsze No, it doesn't, it's just an example demonstrating what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can in [C# 6.0](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6). But you would still need to declare the backing field yourself:

```
string error;
string Error => error;
```